# Wondering if the lenght of this domain is too long

Tags: seo, wordpress

Working on the structure of this domain

http://somelongexampledomainname.com/service-areas/orange-county/aliso-viejo/

Wondering if the lenght of the address is too long and how would seo be affected or improved

Comment: I'd say a bigger factor is that that domain isn't really a brand, it just says what you do.

Comment: well that's actually the company name, so you think it's all bad to begin with?

Comment: i'm in the process of creating pages per city in the counties they service so im wondering if this structure is the best method or ?

Answer (score 1):

First, url isn't everything the blogs tell you it is. Yeah, keeping it clean is a good thing to do, but you shouldnt need to move heaven and hell for it.

A simple trick to see if an url is good (assuming you use the proper structure):
**Say it out loud and make someone else type what you pronounce**.

Comment: Thank you! yet im having a little hard time with "Make someone else type what you pronounce." not really sure what you mean

Comment: You say it out loud and somebody else has to write it down. If they do terrible (and it's a regular person), something is wrong with your url.